# Security Concerns with Runtime.exec()

Tags: java

I am using Runtime.exec() to run an executable file. I have been researching and  found out that there could be security concerns when using this in a application. Are there any security concerns when using Runtime.exec() to run an executable file?

Comment: The area is "tricky". I strongly suggest not putting any untrusted data on the command line, even if you have attempted to "sanitise" it.

Comment: upvote for being security aware. Nicely done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest one I can think of is [Command Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection).  YOu want to whitelist what gets run so someone can't run "rm /" via your Runtime.exec.  There are more ways for this to happen than you might think.  For example what if a "directory" name is passed in as "foo; rm -r ; ls".

Another one - if this is a web application - is that the permissions for the application (and therefore your Runtime.exec() command line aren't the same as what the person hitting the web page has.  Which means the person could delete your Tomcat or insert data into a database or ...

Comment: Hmm I see, It is a web application but the user wont be putting in any commands other than maybe the dir/filename. In that case I would need to sanitize the input. Do you know of any other small or big security concerns with Runtime.exec? Thanks for the information!

Comment: Upon more research it seems like that's the only main concern. See for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301485/runtime-getruntime-execstring-safety

Comment: To make this more explicit, you have to sanitize filenames.  My file name can be "/etc/passwd" or "../../../WEB-INF/web.xml".

Comment: If it's a dir/filename that should already exist, you could create a `java.io.File` object first and check `file.exists()` as part of your sanitisation checks.

Comment: @DNA: that's not enough.  In my example, the web.xml file exists, but it isn't one you want a user reading/writing/deleting.  The constraints are going to be business ones.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I said "as _part_ of your checks"; I guess my point was that although the command to be exec-ed is 'outside' of Java, one can still use all the standard Java APIs _first_ to check the filesystem etc, not merely sanitising filenames etc against patterns, but checking them agsint the state of the system.

Comment: Actually, running through `exec` doesn't execute a shell, so `;` and the like shouldn't work. Directory traversal is an orthogonal issue.

Answer (score 3):

@Jeanne Boyarsky: Apparently you cannot inject into Runtime.exec() in the way you mentioned, unless Runtime.exec() first spawns a shell (cmd.exe on Windows or sh/bash/csh/ksh on Linux) to run the command. [Here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_injection_in_Java) is a good link which talks about this.

I wrote a small program to test this out. It takes a command as user input. So if I enter '**pwd**' (Linux system) it will print the current directory to the System Console. This works perfectly.

If however I try and run two commands, as is permitted in Linux, such as **pwd;id** it throws an Exception straight away. The Exception thrown is as follows.

**javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "pwd;ls": error=2, No such file or directory**

Having said that though there is a situation when this can be a problem. If I have a piece of code as follows:

**Process proc = runtime.exec(cmd);**

... the user could provide an input of **sh -c pwd;id**, thus causing a shell to run and then chaining commands inside it.

So in short, best to not use Runtime.exec() if you can help it. If you MUST use it, make sure you canonicalize all user input and allow only specific characters and commands.

[Here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/IDS07-J.+Sanitize+untrusted+data+passed+to+the+Runtime.exec%28%29+method) is a good read on how to write secure code.

Comment: actually, IMHO, "the user could provide an input of sh -c pwd;id," is not really completely true. You see, runtime.exec() takes different forms like runtime.exec(String cmd), runtime.exec(String[] cmds) etc. With the first one, it's really difficult to do a sh -c and commands. But I totally agree with the rest of the advisory in your and others answers. Cheers.