# read Linux terminal output using Python's sub process module

Tags: python, bash, sh

I am running a python on Linux terminal and it requires some bash commands to run while the test is running. So, I am using the subprocess module and running my test commands (bash script). These so-called bash commands might print something on the CLI  which I need to know if it does while I am running my python code in parallel.

for Ex :

```
# running my python TCP server 

subprocess.call(['.\run_some_shell_commands.sh'],shell=True)

while True:
   # I am doing some other python stuff 

   if (CLI_HAS_SOME_OUTPUT_DETECTED):
       #record the output to some variable 


   # doing some more python stuff
```

If I know for sure that **run_some_shell_commands.sh** returns some output for sure, I could simply use **A = subprocess.checkoutput(['.\run_some_shell_commands.sh'],shell=True)**  which would save its output in variable **A**  ..

**Is there any way to grab the last n lines of the terminal ??** so that I can check if that event has occurred and I can assign that to CLI_HAS_SOME_OUTPUT_DETECTED

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Saira

Comment: You're going to need to capture stdout or stderr, which you can do with `capture_output=True`.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh  Apologies for my late reply..  was trying out different stuff with capture_output ..   Want to clarify onething.. the OUTPUT that I am expecting is not from the shell script I'm running..        As far as I understood from the focs ,  **capture_output**  saves the output of whatever shell commands we are trying to execute ..

Comment: In such case  where I am not sure of when that event might happen , I might have to continuously monitor the terminal output for some threshold time and if that happens, I might need to save the text it is printing .. thought of using **script** command , but the linux box is properitary and is not letting me install any packages

Comment: You can run an ongoing script and pipe the output to something else, where you can continually process it. Think carefully about what you need to do, I deleted my original answer because it might have answered your exact use-case.

Comment: I tried something like this and it does the job for me (as of now, not sure how good this approach is though )

Comment: ```                                                                                                                        
import subprocess
import time as t

cmd = [' ']

P = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True)

while True :
        print(P)
        t.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderHuszagh

Comment: That's an okay solution, and yes, it should work. I would likely use `subprocess.run` with `capture_output` set, and then pass `stdout` and `stderr` separately, and then do something with those variables (do your conditional logic).

Comment: You can set `RADAR = False` as a global variable, then update `RADAR` on each iteration (remember to add `global RADAR` in any function you set a global variable). I'd likely run the script a lot less frequently, and just check in much slower intervals.

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
import time as t
cmd = [' ']
P = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True)
while True :
        print(P)
        t.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in **[Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)**. There are two classes of shell commands, *executables* and *inbuilt commands*, in some programming languages this can make a difference, see [How do I listen for a response from shell command in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647499/how-do-i-listen-for-a-response-from-shell-command-in-android-studio/)

Comment: thanks ralf.. I think the point was to use the capture_output (in py3+)